# Push the data from RDS Aurora Postgres to SQS through AWS Glue

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, dataframe

Hi i am working AWS glue spark job.
I have to pull the records from a RDS Aurora Postgres table and creating a dynamic frame from it and push record by record in SQS.

can someone help here

#######################################

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
import boto3

sqs = boto3.resource('sqs')

sqs_queue_url = f"https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ACCID/SampleQue"
queue = sqs.Queue(sqs_queue_url)

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])
job = Job(glueContext)

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

logger = glueContext.get_logger()

df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(catalog_connection = "ams-connection", connection_type="postgreasql",
                                                  connection_options={
                                                                      "dbtable": "input",
                                                                      "database": "ams"
                                                                      })

job.commit()

# iterate over dynamic frame and send each record over the sqs queue

for record in df:

     queue.send_message(MessageBody=record)
```

Comment: Are you running into any issues here? If yes, errors or logs would help.

Comment: I an getting this error "An error occurred while calling o70.getDynamicFrame. empty.reduceLeft"